# Troubleshooting SmartOS VM that won't start

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machines, smartos

I'm running SmartOS 20130405T010449Z with an Ubuntu KVM inside. The Ubuntu VM ran healthily for months, then after a reboot of the physical hardware the vm no longer connects to the network on startup, so I can't ssh into it to check its health.

I can log into SmartOS and start the VM:

```
$ vmadm start [uuid]
```

verify that it's running:

```
$ vmadm list
UUID             TYPE   RAM     STATE     ALIAS
[uuid]           KVM    10240   running   steve
```

and ping it:

```
$ ping steve
steve is alive
```

but when I attempt to drop into the VM's console, the command simply hangs forever:

```
$ vmadm console [uuid]
[hangs forever]
```

I get the same result when I attempt to ssh from inside SmartOS:

```
$ ssh steve
[hangs forever]
```

I can't ssh from other machines on the network, because the Ubuntu VM's IP address never comes up on the network.

What should I try next to access this VM?

Comment: Can you break into the grub prompt and run single user?  This kind of thing is usually caused by one of the services waiting for the network or a device.  You need to find out what it's waiting for.

Comment: @Matt Is single user synonymous with using the boot option with `noimport=true`? If so, yes, I can run single user, but I don't know what to do next; `vmadm list` reports no VMs (presumably because the configuration was not imported) and I don't know how to bootstrap SmartOS's configuration manually.

Comment: Re: services waiting for the network or a device, when I do `vmadm stop [uuid]` I see a warning before the successful stop: `[ID 722105 kern.warning] WARNING: ip_interface_cleanup: cannot open /devices/pseudo/udp@0:udp: error 13`. Initial Googling didn't turn up anything relevant on this warning, but now it's looking more likely as a culprit. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I eventually recovered what I wanted from the VM, so for posterity, here is what I did:

First, I updated SmartOS. I was hesitant at first, fearing data loss, but the upgrade was totally painless: put a new version on a new USB stick, shutdown, swap the sticks, and reboot.

After the update `vmadm console` and `ssh` would still hang when connecting to the VM, so the key insight (I was unaware of this before) was to connect via VNC instead:

```
root@smartos $ vmadm info [UUID] vnc
{
  "vnc": {
    "host": "192.168.1.7",
    "port": 64762,
    "display": 58862
  }
}

me@anotherMachine $ xtightvncviewer 192.168.1.7::64762
```

There, the problem was immediately apparent: the VM was stuck at the boot menu, waiting for a boot option to be selected. I selected the default option and hey presto, the VM came up perfectly healthy.

There was a catch, though: presumably when I updated SmartOS, I lost the "external" NIC, so the VM came up without a channel to the outside world. I had to manually edit `/usbkey/config` in SmartOS and add these lines, which were missing:

```
external_nic=[MAC address]
external0_ip=192.168.1.20
external0_netmask=255.255.255.0
external0_gateway=192.168.1.1
```

and then add the external NIC to the VM:

```
root@smartos $ cat add_nic.json
{
    "add_nics": [
        {
            "physical": "net1",
            "index": 1,
            "nic_tag": "external",
            "mac": "[MAC address]",
            "ip": "192.168.1.8",
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "gateway": "192.168.1.1"
        }
    ]
}
root@smartos $ cat add_nic.json | vmadm update [UUID]
```

I had to reboot SmartOS to pick up the configuration change, and then the VM came up with a network interface.

Caveat: `vmadm console` still won't work, for some reason; it still hangs indefinitely. However, `ssh steve` works from inside SmartOS, and I can ssh to the IP address from other machines on my network.